# Language component in URL of default Identity UI for asp.net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I have an application which I must port to asp.net 6. I try to implement the authentication logic with scaffolded default identity UI pages.
The application uses URLs which start with a path component which holds the user’s language, then followed by the concrete path components. Something like:

```
/{language}/product/{product}
```

Now I try to establish this url schema also with the asp.net identity default UI pages. For example, the login page url should be look something like this:

```
/en/login
/fr/login
/it/login
```

However, up to now I had only little success in doing so. In changing the @page directive in the scaffolded pages I was able to introduce the {language} path component. However, how do I now tell the cookie middleware to integrate the current {language} placeholder into the redirect? Something like this:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {        
        options.LoginPath = "/{language}/Login"; 
    });
```

Is this feasible in some way or another or is there even a more solid way to accomplish the goal?

**Update**
Up to now I came up with a solution and posted it as an answer, since it works. However if anybody knows a more sophisticated approach, please post it, I feel that the way I did this is really ugly and I cannot believe that there is no cleaner way to accomplish this, since also Microsoft uses the Url schema I try to implement in their websites.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility I've found is to use the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Events-instance`. This seems a feasible way, however it seems to me extremely brutish and one has to register to every event which is concerned and every scaffolded page has to be changed (redirects etcetera).
However, as long as no other solution is provided, this may help someone:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {        
    options.LoginPath = "/language/Login"; 
    options.Events.OnRedirectLogin=>(context){
       // here would stand some Ajax-checks ...
       var myLanguage= ... // detection of the language from the query string
       context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri.Replace("/language/", myLanguage));
       }
    });
```

The above code is best refactored in a new class which derives from `CookieAutenticationEvents`, where then proper handling can be done for each event. So the only assigment in the Program.cs file is the assignment of the custom authentication events class. The original class seems a bit quirky and depending on the purpose of the derived class, it is either better to initially assign custom events while constructing the instance or to override the methods which raise the assigned event handlers.

Within the pages, the language can be declared via the page directive:

```
@page "/{language}/login"
@page "/{language}/loginWith2fa"
etcetera
```

The code behind then will be changed, for example the signature of the get and set method will be extended with the language-parameter.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string language,bool rememberMe, string returnUrl = null) {
```

and additionally, any url references in the code behinds must be changed. Since this way is so ugly, I tried to completely abstain from the default identity ui. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70943309/340628) I ask for a way to do so.