# ASP.NET Core 6 non Default Identity UI based Authentication with email/sms based TFA

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I have to port a website which has a TFA authentication via sms/email to asp.net 6. The client doesn’t want to use an authenticator app. The application has some specialities such as the language of the user in the URL path as the first component.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70898064/340628) I searched a way to introduce the language part and was, although in a very ugly manner, successful.

However I'm also quite unhappy to use the default UI in general for this application, since I have to manually deactivate all the things that are not required but are included in the library. It feels extremely untidy to have such a huge framework of pages active for so little of required functionality. The only things I need are

- Login with a username and password
- Optionally checking a tfa email/sms code if the user has configured its account for this.

The configuration of the user's profile is done in another application and should not be included in this application (hence all the default identity ui stuff has to be deactivated).

I tried to create the authentication logic manually via controller actions and not installing the default ui at all. For the login with username and password, this was fairly easy.

However, setting up the TFA part seems quite tedious and dangerous (from a security perspective). I have not found any documentation what resources have to be registered and how to setup the authentication system.

Is searching out all the required dependencies and creating the code from the Microsoft source code of default identity UI the only way?
Or is there a template solution to accomplish the desired goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there seems no such information available, I gathered the necessary code from the ms source code. Maybe it helps someone:

**Registration**
Copied out of the ms source code, here the required registrations:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MyUserType>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator, TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator<MyUserType>>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<MyUserType>>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        // options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
        {
            o.LoginPath = [your login path];
            o.LogoutPath = [your logout path];
        })
        //.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, o =>
        //{
        //    o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        //    o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        //})
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme;
            o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidateAsync<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator>
            };
        })
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
            o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        });
```

The registration for the external authentication is commented out, maybe someone wants to use that also, therefore i have not directly removed it from the code. The login path can be set accordingly to your login-action. See my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70930111/340628) about how to extend the login url to introduce language and other path components.

**Controller-code**
The controller's action code and views can then derived from the original default identity ui code. The `AddDefaultTokenProviders` call is required to have the email token provider registered.

**Result**
In this way, the default ui and all its abundant functionality is no more in the project and one can selectively decide, what parts to integrate.